# Set interpolation method in scipy.ndimage.map_coordinates to nearest and bilinear

Tags: python, python-3.x, image-processing, scipy, ndimage

I want to set the interpolation method of scipy.ndimage.map_coordinates to 
bilinear and nearest(2 different for different examples).

There is nothing mentioned in the documentation about how to change the interpolation method.There is the following statement written in it which I am unable to comprehend.

> order : int, optional
>   The order of the spline interpolation, default is 3. The order has to be in the range 0-5.

Does this implies that in scipy.ndimage.map_coordinates only the spline interpolation is allowed?
What I am missing and how to change the interpolation.
P.s-I need it to change for elastic deformation task

Comment: There's nothing implied about it.  The function description states explicitly `"The value of the input at those coordinates is determined by spline interpolation of the requested order."`  There may be other interpolators that use the method you want, but this isn't one of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get what you want with:

- `order=0` for nearest interpolation
- `order=1` for linear interpolation

### Example

```
a = np.arange(12.).reshape((4, 3))
inds = np.array([[0], [0.7]]) 
ndimage.map_coordinates(a, inds, order=0) # returns [1.0]
ndimage.map_coordinates(a, inds, order=1) # returns [0.7]
```

### Why

Interpolation with a zero-order spline *is* nearest neighbor interpolation, and interpolation with a first-order spline *is* linear interpolation.  From [this paper](http://bigwww.epfl.ch/publications/unser9902.pdf):

> ...splines of degree 0 (piecewise constant) and splines of degree 1 (piecewise linear) ...

Comment: Is the result of bilinear same as linear?

Comment: Yes. If your input is 2d, the order=1 case will be the same as bilinear interpolation.

Comment: Is there any effect of setting the argument `mode` in it, like does different values alter the effect?

Comment: Also, I am getting "Fatal Python Error: Cannot recover from stack overflow` when I use order = 1

Comment: yes `mode` will change things - but only for indexes outside the "boundaries" of the image.  re: the error - I don't know, that might be data dependent - try to come up with a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and consider making a question about it.

Comment: oops, you [did make a question about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57810275/getting-fatal-python-error-cannot-recover-from-stack-overflow-while-applying-bi)